# Converting FBX file to SCN file for the ARKit

Tags: ios, animation

I want to convert my fbx file I made in Maya (2017) to a scn file for the ARKit of iOS 11. What steps do I take to convert the file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to export your Maya model as a Collada (.dae) file using the available Maya Collada export plugin which you can locate via web search.